# Не обновляется изображение в Image

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `<Image x:Name="Zoomage" Height="100" Width="150" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">`, в котором долна в реалином времени отображаться картинка. Мы получаем ее в цикле и выводим с помощью:

```
form.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
     form.Zoomage.Source = ImageSourceForBitmap(image);
}));
```

Однако изображение просто не обновляется. Возможно  нужно делать это через Binding с использованием *INotifyPropertyChanged*, но я не могу понять, как это сделать.

Comment: Так оно у вас невидимое же: `Visibility="Hidden"`

Comment: @АндрейNOP прошу прощения, забыл убрать. Это в коде изменяется перед началом работы

Comment: Ну тогда приводите пример, который можно запустить и посмотреть, потому что у меня такой же код работает нормально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А функция ImageSourceForBitmap у вас правильно работает? Может там происходит неверное создание BitmapImage и он просто оказывается пустой?

А по поводу Binding скажу следующее: не обязательно связывать data и view через Binding. Это всего лишь один из способов. Чтобы решить вашу задачу через Binding необходимо сделать следующее:

1. Реализуем интефейс INotifyPropertyChanged.

   ```
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
   {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
   }
   ```
2. Создаём проперти Bitmap к которому будем делать привязку.

   ```
   private BitmapImage image;
   public BitmapImage Image
   {
       get
       {
           return image;
       }
       private set
       {
           image = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Image");
       }
   }
   ```

OnPropertyChanged("Image") - уведомляет view о изменении проперти с имеем "Image". После этого view "забиндинное" на это проперти запросит метод get у него и получит новые данные.

3. В конструкторе страницы укажите DataContext.

   this.DataContext = this;

В данном случае this, потому что данные которые "биндятся" находятся в этом же классе. По хорошему надо применять MVVM.

4. Изменяем XAML для использования Binding.

   Image x:Name="ImageElement" Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="100"

Вот и готов Binding. Теперь, изменив проперти Image в коде, у вас автоматически изменится ImageElement. Ниже привожу код класса для полноты картины:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BitmapImage image;
    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get
        {
            return image;
        }
        private set
        {
            image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Image");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        //Указывает контекст данные для страницы.
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartShowImages();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Изменяю Image. Картинки 1.png, 2.png, 3.png лежат в корне проекта.
    /// </summary>
    public async void StartShowImages()
    {
        int i = 1;
        while(true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri($@"{i}.png", UriKind.Relative));
            //ImageElement.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($@"{i}.png", UriKind.Relative));
            i++;
            if(i > 3)
            {
                i = 1;
            }


        }
    }

    #region Реализация INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Ага, спасибо, понял, в чем была моя ошибка. ImageSourceForBitmap работает нормально

Comment: В чем же была ошибка?

Comment: В реализации INotifyPropertyChanged накосячил